# CSS border-box with border causes unnecessary scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I have made this example http://jsfiddle.net/drulia/34TKp/

basically whenever I combine `border` with `border-box` the js scrollHeight becomes 1px bigger then it suppose to be. As you see in example the parent element has no height set, it has `overflow:auto;` just for visual purposes to show that for some reason scrollbar appears.

If you try to comment `border-top` or `box-sizing`, you'll notice that scrollbar disappears and `offsetHeight` becomes equal to `scrollheight`.

It really driving me crazy and so far I'm glad that I found what css properties causing this problem, but I'm curious maybe someone knows why things happen the way they happen?
this happens on FF, Chrome and IE10, I just didn't included prefixed box-sizing for FF in example.

**Update**

Just to clarify - I'm asking why combination of `box-sizing` with `border` causes this problem? Am I doing something wrong or there is a bug, or this suppose to be an expected behaviour, which I'm very doubt.

I do know about simple fixes, like changing overflow property, removing border, etc.

Comment: It has to do with the `overflow: auto` on the parent. box-sizing needs to be on the parent (jspPane) and not on the `.item`'s and it will work. You can also remove `overflow: auto` and it works. Not sure exactly why this is happening..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
.jspPane {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

To:

```
.jspPane {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34TKp/2/

Or you can keep the css as you have it, but add a height attribute to `.jspane`. If you don't want to set a height you can add `display:table;` to `.jspane`

**UPDATE**

Just read your update/edit. I would say because the border attribute adds to the height/width. In your case, you've got  `border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;` for `.item`. You've set it with a height of 35px, but the border-top adds 1px onto this. If you change the height from 34px to 35px then this will fix it. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/34TKp/3/

Comment: Maybe I haven't made my question clear, I do know these simple fixes, I can simply remove box-sizing as well, but my question is why does it happens? why combination of box-sizing with border cause this problem, am I doing something wrong or there is a bug?

Comment: That's a good thinking, it really makes sense, with `box-sizing: border-box;` border becomes part of elements main height, that reduces the available space in element by `1px` in this case and `line-height` doesn't fit inside any more, hence why problem gets fixed once you add additional pixel to height or removing attribute `box-sizing`. thanks for your thoughts!